# How to define custom table mapping by Config.groovy entry in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

I'm developing a plugin that needs a specific index configuration in table mapping.

```
static mapping = {
    myProperty index:'myProperty_Idx'
}
```

Is it some way to let plugin users decide if they want to use or not this mapping via Config.groovy file?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can read the config variables right from your mapping block.

So this line in the app consuming your plugin's Config.groovy

`grails.myplugin.useIndexForFoo = true`

Should allow you to have a configurable domain class, such as

```
class Foo
{
    String myString

    static mapping = {
        if (Holders.config?.grails?.myplugin?.useIndexForFoo)
            myString index: "myString_idx"
    }
}
```

Note I have used Holders rather than injecting grailsApplication bean because mapping config is static - do not know if this is optimal or not